# how can i solve this integral (steps included)?

Tags: integration

My doctor challenged me to solve this integral and I tried my best, please help me ?!
$$
\int \frac{1}{\cos \theta}\, d\theta
$$

Comment: The substitution $t = \tan(\theta/2)$ might work.

Comment: @Nova3335 I'm sure he'd prefer that you solve the challenge by yourself.